# Drive information like Windows 7?

Tags: nautilus, windows-7, drive, style

In Windows 7 the `Computer` area has drives sorted by `Type` which list the size remaining and a progress bar to represent the size currently in use.

Is there a way to customize Ubuntu 11.04 to do the same? (No previous modifications made)

[image]

I want to style the Computer section to look like Windows 7, not use what's already there.

Comment: Never used Windows 7 - can you add a screenshot of what you are talking about?

Comment: @fossfreedom http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1287&bih=690&q=Windows+7+Computer&gbv=2&oq=Windows+7+Computer&aq=f&aqi=g7&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1443l3503l0l4512l18l16l0l3l3l0l259l2156l0.10.3l13l0

Comment: ok - the question refers to "customise" - customise what part of ubuntu?  Nautilus?

Comment: @fossfreedom yes. Natty Narwhal's File Browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open **System monitor** and click on **File system** tab you will see all the Drive info there like this:

[image]

And when you open any directory under home directory you will see some info on the status bar. like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but no. I want to style the `Computer` section to look like Windows 7, not use what's already there.

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus is entirely free software. You can customize it any way you wish. But to be honest, if you're using the Computer section of Nautilus very frequently, I think you should reexamine the way you work with Ubuntu. I had completely forgotten that it even existed and I believe it'll go away or at least be less accessible in 11.10.